# Riverpod's ConsumerWidget not recognized in my flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have installed Riverpod in my flutter project and I'm trying to create a class that extends ConsumerWidget but the latter is not recognized by my IDE (Android Studio) and it underlines it in red even though everything seems to be correct.

Here's my class :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testproject/models/message_model.dart';
import 'package:riverpod/riverpod.dart';

class MessageList extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    List<Message> messages = ref.watch(todosProvider);
    return widget();
  }
}
```

And here's my pubspec file :

```
name: testproject
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.1+2

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cool_alert: ^1.1.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  http: ^0.13.3
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.9
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.4
  firebase_core: ^1.4.0
  overlay_support: ^1.2.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  lint: ^1.5.3
  riverpod: ^1.0.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/notification_icon.png
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  fonts:
    - family: Pacifico
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf
    - family: Source Sans Pro
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf
```

Not sure if I missed something or if I'm doing something wrong but I'm unable to find what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Flutter, you should either use flutter_riverpod or hooks_riverpod (if you are using hooks). Riverpod is dart only.
So you just have to use the proper package.

[image]

Source: https://riverpod.dev/docs/getting_started/#what-package-to-install

Answer (score 5):

The package "riverpod" is for dart programs and so has all the Flutter-related classes stripped out.

Try using [flutter_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) instead, I think that should work.

See the different riverpod packages <s>[here](https://riverpod.dev/docs/introduction/getting_started)</s> (Edit: now [here](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod), see the README).

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the library?

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
```